# Run interval in background iOS Cordova

Tags: ios, ionic2, setinterval

So here’s what I’m trying to do…

I’m using foreground and background location tracking for my Ionic Cordova app. When the user is moving above a certain speed, I’m timing them. The way I time them is by running an interval that increments the count every 1 second. When the app is in the background everything works fine on Android but after a couple minutes running in the background iOS kills the interval.

I already tried enabling background mode too btw

Suggestions??

Comment: That's how background processing works on iOS.  You only get continuous background time if your app is doing something like navigation or VOIP.    If you want continuous updates the user has to be constantly aware.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: If you enable gps-based location updates with "always" permission then you should get location updates about once per second. There is no need for a timer. GPS based location updates will include the current speed as well.

Comment: @Jayce: May I know how did you make it work continously in android? I am facing a similar issue, the timer stops after 5-6 minutes of app in background in android. I have also enabled the background mode plugin.